# How to grep two strings in line by specific order AND calculating values line by line according to my grep

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep, regular-expression

Let's say that I've Python dictionary text which i edited to be human readable. so it's now line by line as the following input.

**Input**

```
{"case":"0901","emailed":"yes","vote":1,"accepted":"no"},
{"case":"0908","emailed":"yes","vote":8,1"accepted":"yes"},
{"case":"0911","emailed":"no","vote":10,1"accepted":"yes"},
{"case":"0090","emailed":"yes","vote":3,1"accepted":"no"},
```

** ALL THE TEXT FILE IN THE PREVIOUS FORMAT **

So i would like to grep lines which include `yes` in first and `no` in second

So am expecting output to be like this

**Output**

```
{"case":"0901","emailed":"yes","vote":1,"accepted":"no"},
{"case":"0090","emailed":"yes","vote":3,1"accepted":"no"},
```

I were unable to find a way to grep by order of words yet.

**And My second question is regarding my output ?**

if i can use `awk` `sum` function in order to calculate the total of vote? which should be `4,1` from the output.

Comment: This looks like a typo: `"vote":3,1"accepted":"no"` -- whats that `1` doing in there?

Comment: @glennjackman it's belong to the number itself which mean's that what between `""` is the number of vote

Comment: *that what between `""`* - there are only `case` numbers between `""` in your input (like `"0901"`)

Comment: this `"vote":3,1` is definitely invalid notation to be a Python dictionary - it could not work

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest thanks for correcting me, yes therefor for `vote` the numbers displayed like that `:3,1`

Comment: After fixing the dict problem, why don't you use python to do what you want, instead of grep or awk?

Comment: @Nick am facing the issue of fetching numbers after `vote` which is not in a closed field !

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη, do you expect `3,1` to be considered as float number `3.1` OR should `1` be ignored?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest as a float number that's why i counted `1,` + `3,1` = `4,1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've python dictionary text

The proper ***Python*** dictionary recovering/processing:

My message is: Python is Python ... you shouldn't garble its data structures

`recover_dict.py` script:

```
import sys, re, ast
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
    items = ast.literal_eval(re.sub(r"(\d+),(\d+)", "\\1.\\2,", f.read().replace('\n','')))
    sum = 0
    for d in items:
        if d['emailed'] == 'yes' and d['accepted'] == 'no':
            sum += d['vote']
            print(d)
print(sum)
```

---

Usage:

```
python recover_dict.py file
```

The output:

```
{'case': '0901', 'vote': 1, 'accepted': 'no', 'emailed': 'yes'}
{'case': '0090', 'vote': 3.1, 'accepted': 'no', 'emailed': 'yes'}
4.1
```

Answer (score 3):

Check this:

#### Printing needed lines

```
awk -F'[,:]' ' 
$4 ~ "yes" && $8 ~ "no" {
    print;
}' input.txt
```

**Output**

```
{"case":"0901","emailed":"yes","vote":1,"accepted":"no"},
{"case":"0090","emailed":"yes","vote":3,1"accepted":"no"},
```

#### Calculating sum

```
awk -F'[,:]' ' 
$4 ~ "yes" && $8 ~ "no" {
    sum += $6"."$7;
}
END {
    print sum;
}' input.txt
```

**Output**

```
4.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
grep 'yes.*no' yourfile \
    | sed -e 's/.*vote":\([0-9,]\+\).*/\1/g' -e 's/,/./g' \
    | paste -sd+ | bc
```

should work for you.

**Explanation**

- `grep 'yes.*no' yourfile`

If you want to `grep` by order of words, but don't know what is in between, use `.*` to match any non-whitespace character repeated zero or more times. Output (with your input file):

```
$ grep 'yes.*no' inputfile
{"case":"0901","emailed":"yes","vote":1,"accepted":"no"},
{"case":"0090","emailed":"yes","vote":3,1"accepted":"no"}
```

- `sed -e 's/.*vote":\([0-9,]\+\).*/\1/g' -e 's/,/./g'`

Match a number (digits and possibly `,`), if preceded by `...vote":` in the output of the `grep` above, and substitute `,` with `.`. Outputs

```
$ grep 'yes.*no' inputfile | sed -e 's/.*vote":\([0-9,]\+\).*/\1/g' -e 's/,/./g'
1.
3.1
```

- `paste -sd+`

Substitutes the newline between your numbers with `+`, outputs:

```
$ grep 'yes.*no' inputfile | sed -e 's/.*vote":\([0-9,]\+\).*/\1/g' -e 's/,/./g' | paste -sd+
1.+3.1
```

- `bc`

Executes  the operation above (`1.+3.1`), outputs:

```
$ grep 'yes.*no' inputfile | sed -e 's/.*vote":\([0-9,]\+\).*/\1/g' -e 's/,/./g' | paste -sd+ | bc
4.1
```